# Where can I find the texlive 2020 universal binaries, for ARM macOS?

Tags: mac, texlive-2020

I would like to find the universal binaries for texlive 2020, so that they run natively on macOS machines with ARM chips.

I have read that MacTeX-2020 and BasicTeX-2020 released such universal binaries but the links are now dead.

Comment: There are universal binaries available for TeX Live 2021 but I don't think there were any for TeX Live 2020. You can get MacTeX-2021 (which installs the full TeX Live 2021 and sets it all up to just work) at <[https://www.tug.org/mactex/](https://www.tug.org/mactex/)>. PS: run TeX Live Utility after installing to fully update TeX Live with all the updates since release.

Answer (score 1):

Install MacTeX from <https://www.tug.org/mactex/>. It will install a full TeX Live 2021 with Universal-Darwin code with no need to set up PATH, etc. It just works out of the box. It also install GUI applications: TeXShop, BibDesk, LaTeXiT and TeX Live Utility.

Comment: I am well aware of all of that but this is going to provide me the 2021 universal binaries and not the 2020 ones.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will be to use/install the [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org) system on your mac and then install a texlive-bin package using

```
sudo port install texlive-bin
```

from your console

Comment: The problem with using a third-party package manager is that they often will run behind on updates.

Comment: That's true. The only solution that I see for that is to contribute yourself to the MacPorts project (https://github.com/macports/macports-ports). TBH its a fairly easy process I do it myself when I need the package updated faster;-)

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes there was a package of Universal Binary for 2020. Assuming you have the binaries in /usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-darwin get the MacTeX-2020-Universal.pkg from <https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/>. That will replace the binaries in that directory with Universal versions but will not change the name of the directory.

Comment: I tried to extract the binaries from MacTeX-2020-Universal.pkg but I failed to find them.

Comment: @DamienL : The binaries are there. But you don't ``extract'' them. Double click the .pkg file to open the installer, follow the directions and let it install them in the correct location with correct permissions, etc.

Comment: Is there another way than double clicking the .pkg file?

Comment: The installer package will do all the necessary pre- and post- install p;rocessing so that things just work. I wouldn't suggest any other way.

Comment: This installer just fails on my machine.

Comment: In what way does it fail? What happens? What is/are the message(s)? What OS version are you running?

Comment: It just says that an error occurred and one should contact the editor of the software. Anyway, I am really looking for the binaries, not to have binaries installed in the MacTeX way.
Maybe the simplest would be that I compile them myself, is this hard to do, where can I get the source code?

Comment: Understand that the Intel binaries run fine under Rosetta on ARM systems. You do need to have the OS load Rosetta (it's not loaded by default) by running an Intel only GUI application; you get a dialog box about loading Rosetta.